# How to add post reference field to a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta

I am trying to add a field to a custom post type through a plugin I am creating.

One of the fields I need is a post reference / link to field. Any ideas on how to do this?

In the WYSIWYG when you are adding a link, there is an area that lists existing posts ... I am looking to add this functionality to a custom field / meta box.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: @s_ha_dum In the WYSIWYG when you are adding a link, there is an area that lists existing posts ... I am looking to add this functionality to a custom field / meta box.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense! Please [edit] that into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something similar to WYSIWYG link dialog by generating traditional HTML SELECT with OPTIONs as post items, and then make it more interactive (searchable,...) with [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jQuery library. It's not as precise solution as that in editor, but it can be enough for you.